# Turn off output of Sys.setlocale()

Tags: r

When I change the locale, there is an output to the console:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE")
[1] "de_DE"
```

How do I turn off this output?

Comment: Either `invisible(Sys.setlocale(...))` or capture it and ignore/discard the variable as in `ign <- Sys.setlocale(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `invisible` ?

```
invisible(Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE"))
```